# How can I check if the array of objects have all values duplicate?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
var values = [
    { name: 'Car',Data:'Required',value:'Vehicle' },
    { name: 'Auto',Data:'Required',value:'Vehicle'},
    { name: 'Bike',Data:'Required',value:'Vehicle'},
    { name: 'Car',Data:'Required',value:'Vehicle' }
];
```

> Duplicate object will be:
>                                { name: 'Car',Data:'Required',value:'Vehicle' }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if an array contains the same item on a different index and by that, understand that there is a duplicate:

```js
const values = [
    { name: 'Car',Data:'Required',value:'Vehicle' },
    { name: 'Auto',Data:'Required',value:'Vehicle'},
    { name: 'Bike',Data:'Required',value:'Vehicle'},
    { name: 'Car',Data:'Required',value:'Vehicle' }
];

const duplicates = values.filter((item, idx) => values.findIndex(i => item.name === i.name && item.Data === i.Data && item.value === i.value) !== idx);

console.log(duplicates);
```

Comment: its returning empty even if duplicate row exists

Comment: @Npsad - Running my code snippet shows it works. Paste your array here..

Comment: const array = <FormArray>this.chatForm.controls['conversation'];
    let temp=[];
    temp.push(array.value)                                                                                              const duplicates = temp.filter((item, idx) => temp.findIndex(i => item.createdBranch === i.createdBranch && item.responseType === i.responseType && item.query === i.query) !== idx);

    console.log(duplicates);
dynamic values from form am getting and pushing to temp

Comment: That is not an array.

Comment: Yeah i got it !!!  this solution Works Fine a small little tweak from my codebase was needed thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check all the properties of objects, you have to introduce a new function, and use it to filter your array:

```js
var values = [
    { name: 'Car',Data:'Required',value:'Vehicle' },
    { name: 'Auto',Data:'Required',value:'Vehicle'},
    { name: 'Bike',Data:'Required',value:'Vehicle'},
    { name: 'Bike',Data:'Required',value:'Different VL'},
    { name: 'Car',Data:'Required',value:'Vehicle' }
];

Object.compare = function (obj1, obj2) {
 //Loop through properties in object 1
 for (var p in obj1) {
  //Check property exists on both objects
  if (obj1.hasOwnProperty(p) !== obj2.hasOwnProperty(p)) return false;
 
  switch (typeof (obj1[p])) {
   //Deep compare objects
   case 'object':
    if (!Object.compare(obj1[p], obj2[p])) return false;
    break;
   //Compare function code
   case 'function':
    if (typeof (obj2[p]) == 'undefined' || (p != 'compare' && obj1[p].toString() != obj2[p].toString())) return false;
    break;
   //Compare values
   default:
    if (obj1[p] != obj2[p]) return false;
  }
 }
 
 //Check object 2 for any extra properties
 for (var p in obj2) {
  if (typeof (obj1[p]) == 'undefined') return false;
 }
 return true;
};


var doubles = values.filter((x,i,a) =>a.slice(0,i).find(y=>Object.compare(x,y)))

console.log(doubles)
```

Comment: This won't work. Check [**this fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/yteLfu5c/). You're only ever checking if `name` is duplicate, whereas the OP specifically asked for a solution pointing to objects whose **all** values are duplicates (i.e. same as `DISTINCT` in SQL). Perhaps the question is a bit poorly worded.

Comment: OK, I changed my code. Please reconsider your downvote.

Comment: Nice! :) I did revoke it, but I really need to hit it, right now (4:15 AM) - so I can't validate your code. Maybe I'll check it out later.

Comment: OK I hope you  won't forget it ;)

Comment: Oh! [Tested it again](https://jsfiddle.net/gyohza/vxbrgL47/2/) - I love what you did there! Nice recursion. Earned an upvote. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Working ahead from the answer in:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/840808/11057988

```js
var findDuplicates = (arr) => {
  let sorted_arr = arr.slice().sort(sortFunc); // You can define the comparing function here. 
  // JS by default uses a crappy string compare.
  // (we use slice to clone the array so the
  // original array won't be modified)
  let results = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < sorted_arr.length - 1; i++) {
    if (sortFunc(sorted_arr[i + 1], sorted_arr[i]) === 0) {
      results.push(sorted_arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return results;
}

var values = [
    { name: 'Car',Data:'Required',value:'Vehicle' },
    { name: 'Auto',Data:'Required',value:'Vehicle'},
    { name: 'Bike',Data:'Required',value:'Vehicle'},
    { name: 'Car',Data:'Required',value:'Vehicle' }
];

var sortFunc = (a, b) => {
  return   (a.name !== b.name) ? a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
         : (a.Data !== b.Data) ? a.Data.localeCompare(b.Data)
         : a.value.localeCompare(b.value);
};

console.log(`The duplicates are ${JSON.stringify(findDuplicates(values))}`);
// prints The duplicates are [{"name":"Car","Data":"Required","value":"Vehicle"}]
```

Couple of differences from original answer:
 1. The `sortFunc` is defined as per your data.
 2. Since your input is array of objects, the `sortFunc` is reused for equality check.

Comment: its returning empty even if duplicate row exists

Comment: If you run the code snippet in the browser, it prints the result with duplicate.